# Get to do something: what's the meaning here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the book I'm reading, a man is having a fight with his wife. He wants to move to another place, but she wants to continue living where they live. He will force her to move although she doesn’t want. At some point of the conversation, he says:

> Husband: «You have to take care of our son. But I have to take care
>   of everyone. You can’t say anything about it.»
>
> Wife: «**Why do you get to make the choices?** Why don’t you think about me?»
>
> Husband: «I am thinking about you!»

What’s the meaning of the sentence in bold? Is it something like: “Who told you that you had to make the choices for everyone of us?”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To **get to do something** is to be allowed to do it, or to have the opportunity to do it.

When the wife asks "Why do you get to make the choices?", she is asking, "Why are you allowed to make the choices?" The wife is complaining about the man's behavior; she is upset because he is making the decisions, and he is not allowing her to make any decisions.

Answer (score 0):

She is questioning his authority to overrule her objections. "Why do you get to make the final decision?"